# Get old text from change event?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, flex3

Can I somehow find out what was the change in the textfield? I would want to compare the old text with the new text ... the problem is, that I have multiple textAreas in a tab-editor, and all the textAreas are watched by one eventListener. I want to get a value calculated by the next formula:

`globalChangeCount += thisTextArea.currentCharacterCount - thisTextArea.oldtCharacterCount`

where the globalChangeCount is a value modified by all changes in any of the textAreas.

I am searching for these values through the event variable, but can't seam to find the old text of the textArea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may or may not be what you're looking to do:

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.TextArea;


    public class CountingTextArea extends TextArea
    {

        public var staleText : String = "";

        [Bindable("textChanged")]
        [NonCommittingChangeEvent("change")]
        public function get charDiff() : int
        {
            var diff : int = staleText.length - text.length;
            staleText = text;
            return diff;
        }

        public function CountingTextArea()
        {
            super();
        }
    }
}
```

I made it so that you can use it as a source for binding. Instead of subscribing to the event on each TextArea, you can use:

```
function addWatchers():void
{
    ChangeWatcher.watch(countingTextArea1, ["charDiff"], charDiffChangeHandler );
    ...
    ChangeWatcher.watch(countingTextArea5, ["charDiff"], charDiffChangeHandler );
}
```

With the event handler somewhere too:

```
function charDiffChangeHandler( event : PropertyChangeEvent ) : void
{
    trace(event.currentTarget.charDiff);
    // or
    trace(event.newValue);
}
```

Comment: I didn't work with flags or what are those above the function, but it seams to be a solution for me.... how do I call this function, or does it automatically do this for me, and the only thing is to get that staleText when I catch the change event from outside the class ex. event.currentTarget.staleText?

Comment: See updated above. I'm not sure how notification works here yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event.currentTarget to get a reference to the TextArea that fired the event, and use the focusIn event to execute a function to populate a variable with the old text value.

Comment: I know I can get the textArea's variables through the event.currentTarget, but I didn't get it, what's with the focusIn ... the oldText is not the text what was before the textArea got focus, but its the text right before the change.

Comment: If focusIn is not late enough for you, I think you have to listen for both keyDown (for keypresses that actually input text, and for ctrl+c and its equivalents) and click (in case of copying via context menu) events, and have those event listeners point to the same function to implement your logic.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should just subclass the `TextArea` and create an `oldText` field variable you update internally after all the external listeners have been notified.

Comment: How to update this oldText variable, because if I catch the event inside with Event.CHANGE I won't get the old velue. I don't want to watch KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN or similar, because text can be inserted without keypress too (copy/paste). How can I cath an event (or something) right before the Event.CHANGE? (after every keydown and copy/paste too)